# Java code for an oracle access failed,during execution. How do i fix my code?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I must encapsulate my access to the Oracle database in one java class, called dbconf:

```
package DB_Oracle_Connection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;




  public class dbconf {

  private String connstr;
  private Connection connect;
  private PreparedStatement prepstat = null;

  public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        connstr = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";

        try {
                String uname = "fred";
                String pass = "flintstone";


                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");


                connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connstr, uname, pass);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        if (connect != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected to the database!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }

            return connect;
    }


public PreparedStatement prepareStatement (Connection conn,String sql_code)
    throws SQLException {
prepstat = conn.prepareStatement(sql_code);
return prepstat;
}
}
```

In my the second java class DB_Oracle_Insert_Statement i call dbconf.

```
package DB_Oracle_Connection;

import DB_Oracle_Connection.dbconf; 
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
public class DB_Oracle_Insert_Statement {

public static void main(String[] args) {    
try {

 dbconf connect = new dbconf();

 // create our java preparedstatement using a sql update query
 PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement((Connection) connect, "INSERT INTO MKR_TEST1       VALUES ( ?, ?, ? , ?)");

 System.out.format("INSERT MKR_TEST1 VORNAME, NACHNAME, ADRESSE\n");
 // set the preparedstatement parameters
 ps.setString(1,"zzzzzVORNAME");
 ps.setString(2,"zzzzzNACHNAME");
 ps.setString(3,"zzzzADRESSE");
 ps.setString(4,"11");

 // call executeUpdate to execute our sql update statement
 ps.executeUpdate();

 //System.out.format("COMMIT\n");

 //PreparedStatement ps1 = connect.prepareStatement(
   //      "COMMIT");
 // call executeUpdate to execute our commit statement
 //ps1.executeUpdate();

 ps.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}


}


}
```

My compiler eclpise says everything is fine with my code. But when I execute my code
Got an exception!

> class DB_Oracle_Connection.dbconf cannot be cast to class
>   java.sql.Connection    (DB_Oracle_Connection.dbconf is in module
>   DB_Oracle_Connection of loader 'app'; java.sql.Connection is in module
>   java.sql of loader 'platform')

How do I fix problem in my code ?

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions.Class names should start with upper case character

Comment: `(Connection) connect` - no, you can't do that. `connect` is of type `dbconf`, not `Connection` and the two are in no way compatible with each other.

Comment: What is the benefit of even having your own `prepareStatement` method?  I would remove that method entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Your `connect`is not a class which implements the `Connection` interface which is expected by the prepared statement.

So change `connect` to `connect.getConnection()`

```
PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(connect.getConnection(), "INSERT INTO MKR_TEST1       VALUES ( ?, ?, ? , ?)");
```

or use your private variable in your prepared statement method:

```
public PreparedStatement prepareStatement (String sql_code)
    throws SQLException {
    prepstat = connection.prepareStatement(sql_code);
    return prepstat;
}
```

BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character

Answer (score 0):

your class cannot be casted to a Connection class. It is not in the inheritance hierarchy. So to get the connection object correctly, just call your method `getConnection()` in this way in the class `DB_Oracle_Insert_Statement`

```
...
public static void main(String[] args) {    
try {

 dbconf connect = new dbconf();

 // create our java preparedstatement using a sql update query
 PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(connect.getConnection(), "INSERT INTO MKR_TEST1       VALUES ( ?, ?, ? , ?)");
...
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I have renamed my connection class to DBConf. And I changed the PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(connect.getConnection(), "INSERT INTO MKR_TEST1 VALUES ( ?, ?, ? , ?)");